# Understand Function capturing through map and reduce

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, elixir, reduce

I 'am beginner in Elixir language , so In the blow example

```
iex> Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], 0, &+/2)
      6

iex> Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &(&1 * 2))
     [2, 4, 6]
```

In the reduce method I understand that we **capture** the second arg and we add to it the list values  until  we reach the end of the List .

but in the map method I can't understand how the capturing works?

reference

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "capture the second arg"? From a quick glance through the documentation you linked, it seems to me that capturing, in the context of elixir, refers to using functions as values via the `&` operator. So I'm not sure what capturing an argument would mean.

Comment: OK you are right , if we consider that (using functions as values via & operator) how we can apply that in the map and reduce .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and [`reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) are two different functions.

`map/2` takes some values and a function that takes a single value and applies that function to each element in the collection, effectively transforming it into a list.

`reduce/2` takes some values and a function that takes 2 arguments. The first argument of that function is the element in your collection, while the second is an accumulator. So the function reduces your collection down to a single value.

Using the syntax `&+/2`, this does not capture the second argument. It calls the `+` function on the two arguments. The `/2` is to denote that it has an arity of 2 (it takes 2 arguments). Take the following code as an example.

```
iex(1)> fun = &+/2
&:erlang.+/2
iex(2)> fun.(1,2)
3
```

Here, we set the `+` function to the variable `fun`. We can then apply that function to our arguments in order to get a value.

The other syntax `&(&1 * 2)` creates an anonymous function that takes our one and only argument (represented by `&1`) and multiplies it by 2. The initial `&` just means that it is an anonymous function.

```
iex(3)> fun2 = &(&1 * 2)
#Function<6.118419387/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(4)> fun2.(5)
10
```

They are similar concepts, but slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

`map` returns you new list as a result of applying function on each element of the list

`reduce` returns you result of the computation of applied function over the list - you reduced the whole collection into (most likely) one result eg. integer

In your example:

```
iex> Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], 0, &+/2)
# it equals:
0 + 1 # first step, 1 is out of the list now
1 + 2 # second step, 2 is out of the list now
3 + 3 # last step, 3 is out of the list now, return 6

iex> Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &(&1 * 2))
 [2, 4, 6]
# apply for each element function fn(x) -> 2 * x end, but with syntactic sugar
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three different ways to *express* an anonymous function, when passing it as an argument:

```
Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], 0, fn p1, p2 -> p1 + p2 end)
```

or, using a shorthand and enumerated params:

```
Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], 0, &(&1 + &2))
```

or, explicitly naming the function of the respective arity (`2` for `reduce`, because `reduce` expects a function of arity `2`):

```
Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], 0, &+/2)
```

The latter, while looking cumbersome, is just a common way to write a function name with it’s arity. [`Kernel.+/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#+/2) is a function name here. If you were using your own function as the reducer:

```
defmodule My, do: def plus(p1, p2), do: p1 + p2

Enum.reduce([1, 2, 3], 0, &My.plus/2)
```

All three ways described above are 100% equivalent.

---

JIC: For the mapper those three ways would be:

```
Enum.map([1, 2, 3], fn p -> p * 2 end)

Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &(&1 * 2))

—
```

The third notation is not available here, since there is no such a function, that takes a number and returns it’s doubled value. But one might declare her own:

```
defmodule Arith, do: def dbl(p1), do: p1 * 2

Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &Arith.dbl/1) # map expects arity 1
#⇒ [2, 4, 6]
```